# Telegram bot (Flask app on Google Cloud Run) stops responding after instance reloading

Tags: python, flask, telegram-bot, google-cloud-run, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make my first Telegram bot on Python. I use the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), Flask, run it in Google Cloud Run.
Locally on my machine everything works fine, when I deploy it (using Docker) to Google Cloud Run everything also works fine until the moment when Google Cloud Run stops the instance. That's what I see in Gloud Run logs:

```
[2022-02-23 11:09:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2022-02-23 11:09:24 +0000] [3] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3)
[2022-02-23 11:09:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

After this bot stops responding.

I tried to set up a min inctances feature (set a min-instances=1) but it didn't help, bot stops responding after a while.

This is a part of code from main.py:

```
...
@app.route("/")
def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start), CommandHandler('menu', menu), CallbackQueryHandler(button)],
        states={
            START: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Default Text)$') & (~ Filters.command), start)
            ]},
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel), CommandHandler('menu', menu)],
        allow_reentry=True
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

I guess the problem is that the bot starts only when I make GET request to my Google Cloud URL: app.route("/") is triggered and the main function is started. If the Cloud Run instance stops and I manually request my service URL (that I get from Google Cloud Run, like https://service-name-xxxxx-xx.a.run.app), the bot starts up again. This is a logs from Cloud Run after this:

```
[2022-02-23 11:09:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2022-02-23 11:09:24 +0000] [3] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3)
[2022-02-23 11:09:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

---I manualy requested a service url---

```
[2022-02-23 19:03:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-02-23 19:03:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2022-02-23 19:03:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2022-02-23 19:03:21 +0000] [3] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3
2022-02-23 19:03:21,985 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler started
```

Honestly, I couldn't think of anything better than to keep track of instance restarts and request the URL every time.

I hope for your advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBF, I'm not familiar with Google Cloud Run, but if I understand correctly the point is that you code will only be invoked when a request is made to the app, i.e. it's one of those "serverless" setups - is that correct?

If so: What `updater.start_polling()` does is start a *long running* background thread that fetches updates continuously. To have your bot responsive 24/7 with this method, your script needs to run 24/7. Now the point of serverless setups is that your code only runs *on demand*, so for this hosting method a more reasonable approach would be to only invoke your code when your bot receives an update. This can achieved using a webhook instead of long polling. There is a section on this in the [PTB wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/webhooks#alternative-no-threading). See also [this thread](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/534) about AWS Lambda, which is similar AFAIK.

However one should note that stateful logic like `ConversationHandler` is hard to realize in such setups: By default `ConversationHandler` keeps track of the current state *in memory*, so the information is lost on shutdown of the process. You can use [persistence](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Making-your-bot-persistent) to store the data, but I'm not sure how well this works with serverless setups - there might be race conditions if multiple updates come in at the same time.
So another idea would be to switch to a different hosting service that allows to run your process 24/7.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.